# Please explain the statement, "Containers are lightweight...you can run thousands on a server..."

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, docker, containers

In much of the hype around containers I often hear statements such as:

> Linux containers are very lightweight...you can potentially run
>   thousands of them on a single server...

I understand that by definition containers share the kernel of the underlying OS and that the containers *themselves* (the container daemons) are lightweight but it's not as if someone is going to fire up a thousand empty containers.  There'll be database processes, web servers, jobs of all types running inside the containers and these all have whatever are their typical memory/working set requirements.  So how is the statement about being able to run thousands of containers a practical consideration?

Comment: You _can_ run thousands of database processes, web servers, jobs of all types, if the server is big enough.

Comment: But what's that got to do with containers?  Given enough resources you can run thousands of anything anywhere.  I always see the statement made specific to containers.

Comment: Because, given the _same_ server, you can only run far fewer traditional virtual machines.

Comment: It reads to me like the point **is** that empty containers are lightweight. Why does that matter? Because if you size something based on running X many database processes and then you think, "Oh I want to put these in containers instead" your next question is how much do you have to change your sizing to accomodate X containers in addition to your existing sizing concerns. The concept that the containers themselves are lightweight means you don't have to take them into consideration for sizing except possibly when X is very large.

Comment: The point here is that full-fledged hypervisor diminished the host memory by the amount of memory it's configured with - no matter if it's free inside the hypervisor. Furthermore, containers don't reuse memory for running a separate instance of kernel and various kernel subsystems, which use memory by themselves.

Comment: For the life of me I can't understand why StackExchange lets people downvote without requiring a comment.  I'm open to and looking for constructive feedback so I can improve the question for the benefit of the community. Instead I now feel crappy and don't have a clear sense of what I could do address the downvoter's concerns and improve the question.  I'm a human being myself so I understand the downvoter is irritated by something I wrote or lacking in my question, but for goodness sake, have the guts to air your concern.

Comment: @Robert downvoted for whining about being downvoted.

Comment: @ToddWilcox If you repost your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @drookie Your answer is great as well.  But when you said, "containers don't reuse memory for running a separate instance of kernel and various kernel subsystems" did you mean "containers *do* reuse memory because they don't have to run separate instances of the kernel..."?

Comment: You can't get too down about downvotes, as frustrating as it is to have no explanation. If I had to guess, I'd say the reason in this case was that the answer seems obvious to the downvoter and therefore your question reads like a waste of (their) time. Sometimes a downvote says more about the downvoter than it does about the question. Don't worry about it. If your question makes sense to others, you'll get upvotes, and  one up and one downvote is still positive rep.

Answer (score 1):

It reads to me like the point **is** that empty containers are lightweight. Why does that matter? Because if you size something based on running X many database processes and then you think, "Oh I want to put these in containers instead" your next question is how much do you have to change your sizing to accomodate X containers in addition to your existing sizing concerns.

The concept that the containers themselves are lightweight means you don't have to take them into consideration for sizing except possibly when X is very large.

Compared to running separate virtual machines, Michael Hampton's comment is relevant:

> Because, given the same server, you can only run far fewer traditional virtual machines.